# Sql Server Modificar columna para que sea autoincremental sin perder la data existente

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Tengo una tabla, en la cual existe un campo con valores generados por una aplicacion (autoincrementales). dicho campo, es del tipo INT.
Necesito modificar este campo, para que sea de tipo Identity(ultimonumero+1,1)
he intentado con el siguiente comando ddl

```
ALTER TABLE miTabla ALTER COLUMN miColumna IDENTITY(15,1);
```

pero esto me da error SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'IDENTITY'.

Existirá alguna forma de poder modificar el campo, sin perder la data previamente almacenada?
Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuánta información tienes?

Comment: es poca información (15 registros)... Pero tampoco puedo modificarla, ya que el campo es autoincremental, y no permite modificaciones, a traves de SET IDENTITY_INSERT miTabla ON

Answer (score 2):

puede que esto te sirva:

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

en `IDENTITY` el primer valor es el valor inicial y el segundo es la proporción en el cual incrementará.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta.. lamentablemente esto no lo puedo ejecutar, ya que perdería la información que ya existe en la tabla en el campo original.

Comment: probaste cambiando el ADD por el SET ? y obvio; omitiendo el DROP

Comment: eso no parece funcionar estimado.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando existen pocos datos, lo ideal es crear una tabla nueva y pasar los datos. Después de eso, eliminamos la tabla original y renombramos la tabla nueva con el nombre original. Pueden existir problemas en caso de que haya objetos que dependan de la tabla original y tengan `SCHEMABINDING`, pero en un ambiente común no debería de haber problema.

Dejo el ejemplo con comentarios paso a paso.

```
--Generamos datos de prueba
CREATE TABLE miTabla(
    miColumna int,
    Col2    datetime,
    Col3    varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO miTabla
VALUES(  1, GETDATE() - 20, 'Prueba 01'),
      (  2, GETDATE() - 19, 'Prueba 02'),
      (  3, GETDATE() - 18, 'Prueba 03'),
      (  4, GETDATE() - 17, 'Prueba 04'),
      (  5, GETDATE() - 16, 'Prueba 05'),
      (  6, GETDATE() - 15, 'Prueba 06'),
      (  7, GETDATE() - 14, 'Prueba 07'),
      (  8, GETDATE() - 13, 'Prueba 08'),
      (  9, GETDATE() - 12, 'Prueba 09'),
      ( 10, GETDATE() - 11, 'Prueba 10')

SELECT *
FROM miTabla;

--Iniciamos la solución abriendo una transacción para hacer todo o nada.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
--Abrimos la opción de manejar errores
BEGIN TRY
    --Creamos una tabla igual pero con IDENTITY
    CREATE TABLE miNuevaTabla(
        miColumna int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Col2    datetime,
        Col3    varchar(50)
    );

    --Permitimos insertar valores explícitos en el IDENTITY
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT miNuevaTabla ON;

    --Insertamos los datos bloqueando toda la tabla para que nadie más la modifique
    INSERT INTO miNuevaTabla WITH(TABLOCKX)(
        miColumna,
        Col2,
        Col3
    )
    SELECT miColumna,
            Col2,
            Col3
    FROM miTabla;

    --Quitamos el identity insert
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT miNuevaTabla OFF;

    --Eliminamos la tabla original
    DROP TABLE miTabla;

    --Renombramos la tabla nueva al nombre original
    EXECUTE sp_rename N'miNuevaTabla', N'miTabla', N'OBJECT';

    --Cerramos la transacción
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --En caso de error, le damos marcha atrás a la transacción y mostramos el error.
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;

--Vemos como la tabla tiene los mismos datos
SELECT *
FROM miTabla;

--Revisamos la estructura de la tabla para ver que tiene el IDENTITY asignado.
EXEC sp_help N'miTabla';

GO
-- Elimino los datos de prueba.
DROP TABLE miTabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien aun le sirve, algo que a mi me ha funcionado muchas veces.
Primero validar que tipo de incremento ya tiene la columna que se quiere poner como auto-incrementable.
Si se determina que el tipo de aumento sea uniforme se puede hacer lo siguiente:

1. Primero respalda tu bd.
2. Validar el último valor de tu campo que vas a modificar y anotalo.
3. Crear una nueva columna auto-incrementable con el nombre del campo original pero agregando un sufijo (ej. ID -> ID_New). Este campo debe tener el valor inicial y el incremento que se esta manejando en la columna original.
4. Una vez creado el nuevo campo, validamos el último valor de este y comparamos con el último dato del campo original, verificando que sea el mismo.
5. Si los datos coinciden, podemos continuar, de lo contrario validamos nuevamente que el incremento de la columna original sea uniforme, de lo contrario será mas complicado.
6. Si el campo que vamos a modificar es calve primaria, eliminamos primero la restricción y luego eliminamos el campo.
7. Por último renombramos la columna creada con auto-incremento al nombre de la columna original que eliminamos anteriormente.
8. Si el campo original era clave primaria no olvidar agregar la clave al nuevo campo renombrado.